# Correct way to create ConfidentialClientApplication that allows retry for Windows Service

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to create Windows Service that will allow me to send emails on behalf of specific users.

Lates version of Graph Client allows specifying retries using `WithMaxRetry`.
Unfortunately, there aren't any good examples showing "best practices" when creating `ConfidentialClientApplication`.

Currently, I use the below code to send email without asking for login and password:

```
const string clientId = "foo...99a0";
const string clientSecret = "#6A...cx#$a";
const string tenant = "1c...7";
const string azureAdInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
var authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, azureAdInstance, tenant);
string[] scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientCredentials = new ClientCredential(clientSecret);
var confidentialClientApplication =
    new ConfidentialClientApplication(
        clientId,
        authority,
        "https://daemon",
        clientCredentials,
        null,
        new TokenCache());

var graphClient =
    new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0", 
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
        async(requestMessage) =>
        {
            var result = await confidentialClientApplication
                .AcquireTokenForClientAsync(scopes);
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = 
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", result.AccessToken);
        }));

var recipients = new List<Recipient>
{
    new Recipient
    {
        EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress
        {
            Address = "test@example.com"
        }
    }
};

var email = new Message
{
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        Content = "Works fine!",
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
    },
    Subject = "Test",
    ToRecipients = recipients
};

await graphClient
    .Users["sender@example.onmicrosoft.com"]
    .SendMail(email, true)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

but I can't figure out how to create `ConfidentialClientApplication` based on recent changes from [Request Context With Middleware Options](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/pull/367).

Because I wasn't able to find up to date example my question is, how should I create `GraphServiceClient` to be able to send emails from Windows Service?

This is code from above PR:

```
HttpProvider httpProvider = new HttpProvider();

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(appOnlyProvider, httpProvider);
graphClient.PerRequestAuthProvider = () => CreateDelegatedProvider();

var me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
    .WithScopes(string[] { "User.Read" }) // adds auth scopes
    .WithMaxRetry(5) // specifies maximum number of retries
    .WithPerRequestAuthProvider()
    .GetAsync();
```

How should I adopt it per my requirement?
I'm new to Graph so I want to avoid bad code.

Answer (score 1):

One of the pieces of the puzzle that I believe you are missing is the new Authentication Providers library that is here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Auth/0.1.0-preview and there are some examples of how to use these Authentication providers here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth

This library provides a set of authorization providers based on the desired OAuth2 flow.  In your case you should use the ClientCredentialsProvider instead of the DelegateProvider.

You don't need to use a PerRequestAuthProvider.  That is only needed for scenarios where you want to switch between different flows or different appIds in each call.

Comment: I didn't know about Microsoft.Graph.Auth, thank You for the link. This lib is in preview and it is missing examples, but that's a good starting point. Example showing how to correctly authorize and create request would complete this answer :)

Comment: Hey @Misiu Can I suggest the 30 Days of Graph blog series.  It is a comprehensive set of articles that help devs get started with Graph https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/announcing-30-days-of-microsoft-graph-blog-series/